# Dynamically produce a DataTable selecting Rows from two other DataTables

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a SQL table which stores the different rates charged to clients.
The table also includes a list of 'default' rates to be used if the client has none specific to them.
What I need, is once the user selects a client from a combo box, to create a table of rates for that client, consisting of the defaults, or the rates specific to that client, or a mix of both, as follows:

```
Client     Type of Work     Rate
ABC Ltd       Type A        100
XYZ & Co      Type B        150
Default       Type A        125
Default       Type B        175
```

So the rates returned would look as follows:

```
ABC Ltd       Type A        100
              Type B        175   (default)
XYZ & Co      Type A        125   (default)
              Type B        150
Anyone else   Type A        125   (default)
              Type B        175   (default)
```

The information in the database is structured as follows

```
Table for clients
Table for Types of Work
Table for Rates   (foreign keys linking to clients and types of work)
```

Can anyone explain how best to obtain the above result using either a SQL statement, a C# routine in the winforms application or a combination of both.

PS. I apologise but I'm unsure how to set my data out in tables on this website.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR

```
public static DataTable TableOfRates(string pIPName = "Default")
    {
        try
        {
            string sqlText1 = "SELECT RateID, IPName, RateName, Rate, DateFrom, DateTo, Active, " +
                              "(RateName + ': £' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Rate) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, " +
                              "(CASE WHEN Active = '1' THEN ' (Active)' ELSE ' (Inactive)' END))) AS ListRate " +
                              "FROM tblRates WHERE IPName IS NULL AND Active = 'true';";
            aSqlQuery cQ1 = new aSqlQuery(sqlText1, "table");
            DataTable defaultRates = cQ1.TableResult;

            string sqlText2 = "SELECT RateID, IPName, RateName, Rate, DateFrom, DateTo, Active, " +
                              "(RateName + ': £' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Rate) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, " +
                              "(CASE WHEN Active = '1' THEN ' (Active)' ELSE ' (Inactive)' END))) AS ListRate " +
                              "FROM tblRates WHERE IPName = '" + pIPName + "' " +
                              "AND Active = 'true';";
            aSqlQuery cQ2 = new aSqlQuery(sqlText2, "table");
            DataTable clientRates = cQ2.TableResult;

            foreach(DataRow defaultRow in defaultRates.Rows)
            {
                string defaultType = defaultRow["RateName"].ToString();
                foreach (DataRow clientRow in clientRates.Rows)
                {
                    string clientType = clientRow["RateName"].ToString();
                    if (defaultType == clientType)
                    {
                        clientRates.Rows.Add(defaultRow.ItemArray);
                    }
                }
            }

            return clientRates;
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            throw new Exception("cRate: Error compiling Table Of Rates (mode = '" + pIPName + "')" + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
        }
    }
```

However, whether I use Add Row, Import Row, or Add Item Array I get errors.  It doesnt seem to like using datarows from more than one table.

Comment: Can you provide sample data (the code to create the tables and data)? Are you sure that you want to do it in memory instead of the database via sql(which would be more efficient/scalable)?

Comment: SQL is a relational data specific language.  That means it likes normalised data.  You're talking about pivotting it for presentation purposes.  I strongly advise you keep the structure who already have when dealing with the data in SQL, only reformatting it in your presentation layer *(In C#, not in SQL)*.  this makes the code more maintainable, adaptable, portable, reliable, etc, by decoupling the layers and reducing hidden dependancies.

Comment: Why not create your own object that holds the data that you need? A DataTable is not for holding small amounts of data from different tables, it's to replicate a table from a relational database in code.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a table that lists clients and jobs - with that in mind you might be doing something like the following

```
SELECT
  CASE R1.RATE WHEN NULL THEN R2.RATE else r1.rate AS RATE END
FROM
  CLIENTJOBS C LEFT JOIN RATES R1 ON
    R1.CLIENT = C.CLIENT AND R1.WORKTYPE = C.WORKTYPE
  JOIN RATES R2 ON
    R2.WORKTYPE = C.WORKTYPE AND R2.CLIENT = 'DEFAULT'
```

bear in mind this is untested guess-code, but hopefully points you in the right direction

Comment: So your suggestion joining the tables twice?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to load up a DataTable:

```
CREATE TABLE 
     #MyTempTable (myColumn1 DataType, myColumn2 DataType, myColumn3 DataType) 
INSERT INTO 
     #MyTempTable(myColumn1, myColumn2, myColumn3)
SELECT 
     f.Bar1, o.Bar2, o.Bar3 FROM FooTable AS f 
INNER JOIN 
     TableFoo o ON f.Bar1 = o.Bar1
```

With some tweaking this script would create a temporary table that persists as long as your connection is kept alive and contains the data from the other tables that you need.